# How to pass an option in a bash script command?

Tags: bash

I have a script starting with:

```
#!/usr/bin/sudo bash
```

It does a non instant processing and is not meant to be interrupted, so I would like to add the -b option to sudo to run it in background *after the password has been entered*.

```
#!/usr/bin/sudo -b bash
```

However, the script does not accept the option. Am I doing something wrong ? Can one even pass an option that way ? And if not, why ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The shebang line generally only accepts a path and one argument. So `-b bash` is being handed to `sudo` as a single argument and likely being treated as the command to run (and possibly then failing entirely).

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/sudo`!!  Seriously!  I almost laughed orange juice out my nose!

Comment: I suppose there may be a use case for running `sudo` in a script, but if you're going to do it, there's no need to put it in the shebang.  Just use `#!/bin/sh` and invoke `sudo bash`.  But doing so is probably not a good idea.  It's not that hard to require the user to invoke sudo explicitly, and far more clear to the caller that root privileges are required.  Unexpected escalation of privilege is a root cause of many security flaws.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I would say it depends. Running a whole script as root where is just needs root permissions for a single action would also not being a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
$ shellcheck yourscript 

In yourscript line 1:
#!/usr/bin/sudo -b bash
^-- SC2096: On most OS, shebangs can only specify a single parameter.
```

A fair workaround is to have the script invoke itself with sudo based on a flag:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == "-n" ]]
then
  echo "Processing as $(whoami)"
else
  printf "Option -n not specified: invoking sudo -b %q -n:" "$0"
  exec sudo -b "$0" -n
fi
```

This has the additional benefit of letting you run `yourscript -n` directly to not invoke sudo and not run in the background. This allows things like `sudo yourscript -n && mail -s "Processing complete" you@example.com` which would not be possible if the script unconditionally backgrounded itself.

Caveat: `sudo "$0"` is not a bullet proof way of reinvoking the current script.